# Regular Expression: Matching a non digit character BESIDES a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression I'm using to autoformat a date field in a text box. I am replacing every non digit value the user attempts to enter with an empty string. How can I restrict them from entering non digit characters BESIDES the slash character ( / )?

i.e. Users should be able to enter in any digit and a slash /

```
var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
val = val.replace(/^([\d]{2})([\d]{2})([\d]{4})$/, "$1/$2/$3");
```

Comment: `/^([\d]{2})\/?([\d]{2})\/?([\d]{4})$/`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negated regex character class like this:

```
[^\d\/]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vP5tT3/1)**

Quoting your code you code use:

```
var val = this.value.replace(/[^\d\/]/g, '');
                              ^^^^^^^ ---- Replace everything but digits and /
```

Comment: Don't you mean `[^\d\/]`

Comment: @N.Leavy exactly lol. Thanks for pointing that. Got dizzy with negating the non digit lol

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to replace everything but a digit `[0-9]` or a slash `[\/]` then should use something like `[^0-9\/]` or if you prefer `[^\d\/]`